# get minute bar historical data from Google finance?

Tags: yahoo-finance, google-finance-api

I can get daily data easily using this link:

```
https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=LHA&x=ETR&i=60&p=1d&f=d,c,h,l,o,v
```

But when I try to change "1d" to "1y" I still get 1 day's data.

I am trying to get 2 years' worth.

Is there a way to do this? yahoo or bing finance would be fine too.

Comment: Here is the python code to get the data http://trading.cheno.net/downloading-google-intraday-historical-data-with-python/

Answer (score 9):

You need to use '1Y', not '1y' on your query to get a time period stretching back 1 year. However, you will also need to change the granularity of your query, as minute data is only available for the previous 5 days.

This query will provide you with minute data for the previous 5 days.

https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=LHA&x=ETR&i=60&p=5d&f=d,c,h,l,o,v

The following query will provide you with the last two years of prices at the close.

https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=LHA&x=ETR&i=86400&p=2Y&f=d,c,h,l,o,v

Answer (score 9):

google API "getprices" is NO more fetching intraday data of any interval (say 1 minute or 5 minute or 60 minutes .....). It is now fetching data in 1 day interval only irrespective of interval set.

Comment: Yes. In previous, we have got full minute ticker data. But now we will get only 1-day interval data as the daily summary :(. Any other api is there for get full minute ticker data?

Answer (score 1):

I tried getting intraday data before, the furthest back I can get is 15 days, i.e. 15d
Using 2w or 1y did not work for me.

references:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32745-get-intraday-stock-price/content/getHistoricalIntraDayStockPrice.m
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221952/Simple-Csharp-DLL-to-download-data-from-Google-Fin

Answer (score 1):

Update [2020]
Google and Yahoo deprecated their APIs so only direct website access works. However, the max resolution you can get is 1 day (end-of-day).

For historical high-resolution data [Tickdata.com](https://tickdata.com) is a good source for tick-level data.

If 1-min bars are sufficient [FirstRateData.com](https://firstratedata.com) has 1-min data for most stocks and fx going back 20 years.